# unable to access object's property despite it being present

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My serializer:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        try:
            print(validated_data)
            print(validated_data.author)
            task = Task.objects.create(**validated_data)
            return task
        except BaseException as e:
            print(e)
            raise HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
```

my view:

```
class TaskCreateApiView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
```

my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Task(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(
        default="",
        max_length=255,
    )
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
    )
    category = models.CharField(
        default="",
        max_length=255,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + self.content
```

My log from serializer:

> {'content': 'test2', 'category': 'test', 'author': <User: zaq1>}
>
> 'dict' object has no attribute 'author'
> print(validated_data.author)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'author'

How can I access `author`? I see it exists as `<User:zaq1>` but can't seem to access it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you print `validate_data.author`, whereas it should be `validate_data['author']`:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        try:
            print(validated_data)
            print(validated_data['author'])
            task = Task.objects.create(**validated_data)
            return task
        except BaseException as e:
            print(e)
            raise HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
```

That being said, normally manually creating in a serializer is a (serious) antipattern: a lot of work in the serializer goes to creating objects with many-to-many fields, or deeply nested data.

Comment: how should it be done better?

Comment: I'll need to send an email on task creation

Comment: @AlexIronside: that belongs in the view so *after* creating the task object.

Comment: hm. Any idea how I can call this create and after create run the code? Since my view is a class

Comment: @AlexIronside: you override `pefom_create` with a super call, and then the email logic: https://www.cdrf.co/3.9/rest_framework.generics/CreateAPIView.html#perform_create